# Relating buttons to app routes in Twitter Bootstrap UI (using with Play Framework 2.0)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I have a question that I know is quite basic, and actually I think none of my googling has turned up an answer precisely because it's so basic. I have a Play 2.0 app with integrated Twitter Bootstrap 3 for the UI, but my issue is (I think) entirely UI-related.

I've created a basic page using one of the provided Bootstrap examples. On it, there's a search box with associated "Search" button. Currently, I can't figure out how to pass the input of the search box to a configured route in my app.

Here's the box/button code:

```
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search for Patient by ID" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
      </form>
```

I've tried adding a link into the button code like this:

```
<button type="submit" a href="@routes.Users.showFhirUserDetails(fhirID: String)" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
```

Because I want the input to the search box to be treated as the parameter fhirID, which is a String. But I get an error that the required parameter for the method showFhirUserDetails() isn't found. My question is- how can I treat the input to a search box (or any field like this) as a certain parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL of form submition need to be given as a forms `action` attribute, additionally if you want to send some fields they need to have `name` attribute, so your code need to look like this:

```
<form action="@routes.Users.showFhirUserDetails()" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="fhirID" placeholder="Search for Patient by ID" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
</form>
```

And in your `routes` file this routes param MUST be set as optional!

```
GET  /show-details  controllers.Users.showFhirUserDetails(fhirID: String ?= null)
```

Check the docs for [optional params](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting#Optional-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  
I'm getting an "Action not found" when I set the route param to be optional, despite the last route being    "GET /emr/bootstrapDetails controllers.Users.fhirUserDetails(fhirID:String ?= null)" And the Users controller does have a method fhirUserDetails(), so I don't understand why the search isnt working. I'm trying a known ID that normally works

Comment: What address is showing in address bar after sending the form ?

Comment: It was an unrelated problem- thanks again. Your answer works perfectly!